# Is it possible to create this HTML table?

Tags: html, html-table

I was wondering if it was possible to recreate this table.

I've been trying several things but I keep getting stuck.

[image: the table.]

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question... i'm only trying to learn..

Comment: Then show us what you learned? But it seems like you are looking for possibilities so yes It is possible

Comment: I've learned that you can fix this problem with rowspan. and I'm really thankfull for the people who helped me out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use

```
rowspan
```

on the `td` or `th` element td element of your table to cover multiple rows

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Col1</th>
    <th rowspan="5">Col2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>March</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>April</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use rowspan:

```html
<table border='1px'>
<tr>
 <td rowspan=5>
 ...
 </td>
 <td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>...</td>
</tr>
</table>
```